# Use AutoMapper to map from an interface to a concrete type

Tags: c#, automapper

#### I've created [a dotNetFiddle that demonstrates the question here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fPQxWx).

---

Here's a simplified example of what I'm trying to do... let's say I have an the following interfaces:

```
public interface IPerson
{   
    int Id { get; set; }     
}

public interface IModelPerson : IPerson
{
    int BeautyCompetitionsWon { get; set; }
}
```

In the real implementation, there are lots of different types of people (e.g. `IUglyPerson`, etc). These are the contracts for entity types, e.g. as follows:

```
public class PersonEntity : IPerson
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class ModelPersonEntity : PersonEntity, IModelPerson
{
    public int BeautyCompetitionsWon { get; set; }
}
```

**Note**: We may also have multiple implementations of each contract type - e.g. `IModelPerson` may also be implemented by `SupermodelEntity`.

We want to map our entity types to DTOs, which look something like this:

```
public abstract class PersonDto : IPerson
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public abstract string PersonType { get; }
}

public class ModelPersonDto : PersonDto, IModelPerson
{
    public int BeautyCompetitionsWon { get; set; }
    public override string PersonType
    {
        get { return "Model"; }
    }
}
```

As such, we create a mapping:

```
Mapper.Initialize(config =>
{
    config.CreateMap<IPerson, PersonDto>()
        .Include<IModelPerson, ModelPersonDto>()
        .ConstructUsing((IPerson person) => 
        {
            if (person is IModelPerson) return new ModelPersonDto();

            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown person type: " + person.GetType().FullName);
        })
        ;

    config.CreateMap<IModelPerson, ModelPersonDto>();
});
```

So, I have two issues here.

**1. Is there any way of creating the mappings without the `ConstructUsing` clause?** I thought that having the more specific version of `CreateMap` would have taken care of this for us, but if I don't have the `ConstructUsing` clause, AutoMapper tells me "Instances of abstract classes cannot be created".

**2. Why don't the properties from my subclasses get mapped?** If I execute a mapping as follows:

```
var source = new ModelPersonEntity { Id = 100, BeautyCompetitionsWon = 9 };
var target = Mapper.Map<PersonDto>(source);
```

The expected value for `target.BeautyCompetitionsWon` is 9, but the actual value is 0.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Question 1: Not that I am aware of.

Question 2: When using the `.ConstructUsing()` make sure you return the mapped object you are after rather than a fresh instance.

e.g.

```
Mapper.Initialize(config =>
{
    config.CreateMap<IPerson, PersonDto>()
        .Include<IModelPerson, ModelPersonDto>()
        .ConstructUsing((IPerson person) => 
        {
            if (person is IModelPerson) return Mapper.Map<ModelPersonDto>(person);

            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown person type: " + person.GetType().FullName);
        })
        ;

    config.CreateMap<IModelPerson, ModelPersonDto>();
});
```