# Maping generic interface to concreate class but using interface definition -> automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

Hey I'm trying to map my generic class to concrete class but using it's interface.

My service returns me data which type is

> IPaggedResults<Customer>

and I want to be able to map this to

> IPaggedResults<CustomerDto>

It works if I invoke mapping with:

**_mapper.Map<PaggedResults<CustomerDto>>**

but I want use following syntax:

**_mapper.Map<IPaggedResults<CustomerDto>>**

```
public class PaggedResults<T> : IPaggedResults<T>
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Results { get; protected set; }
    public int TotalResults { get; protected set; }
    public int TotalPages { get; protected set; }
    public int ResultsPerPage { get; protected set; }

    public PaggedResults(IEnumerable<T> results, int totalResults, int resultsPerPage)
    {
        Results = results;
        TotalResults = totalResults;
        TotalPages = totalResults / resultsPerPage;
        ResultsPerPage = resultsPerPage;
    }
}


public class CustomerDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string NIP { get; set; }
}
```

My mapper configuration:

```
        public static IMapper Initialize()
            => new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<CustomerCompany, CustomerDto>();
                cfg.CreateMap(typeof(IPaggedResults<>), typeof(PaggedResults<>));
                cfg.CreateMap(typeof(IPaggedResults<>), typeof(IPaggedResults<>)).As(typeof(PaggedResults<>));
            }).CreateMapper();
```

Im'using Automapper by Jimmy Bogard.

Comment: what is `_mapper` ???

Comment: I forgot - _mapper is IMapper instance

Comment: But what is `IMapper`, it's a class you created right? put the code

Comment: IMapper is Automapper instance which comes form Automapper library. I put mapper configuration above.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34506150/use-automapper-to-map-from-an-interface-to-a-concrete-type

Comment: I know this solution, but it doesn' t work with open generics types.

Comment: That should work. See also [this](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/353e5adc69aa25d6701133d7a347c9ad4aed3067/src/UnitTests/MappingInheritance/ShouldSupportOnlyDestinationTypeBeingDerived.cs#L146).

Comment: Ok it works partialy. I have one more question: why this "public interface Dummy<out T>
    {
        IEnumerable<T> Data { get; set; }
    }
    " does not work? -> T is used in invariant position.

Comment: Are `CustomerCompany` and `Customer` the same things?

Comment: Yes, they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I could achieve it through the following code:

Create an extension for `IMapperConfigurationExpression`

```
public static class IMapperConfigurationExpressionExtensions 
{
    public static void MapPaggedResults<TSource, TDestination>(this IMapperConfigurationExpression exp){
        exp.CreateMap(typeof(PaggedResults<TSource>), typeof(IPaggedResults<TDestination>))
       .ConstructUsing((source, ctx) => { return ctx.Mapper.Map<PaggedResults<TDestination>>(source) as IPaggedResults<TDestination>; });
    }
}
```

Then use this configuration:

```
public static IMapper Initialize()
=> new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
   cfg.CreateMap(typeof(IPaggedResults<>), typeof(PaggedResults<>));
   cfg.MapPaggedResults<CustomerCompany, CustomerDto>();
}).CreateMapper();
```

Then both results can be obtained:

```
var _mapper = Initialize();
IPaggedResults<CustomerCompany> source = new PaggedResults<CustomerCompany>(
    new List<CustomerCompany>() { new CustomerCompany() {Id =42, Name = "SomeName", NIP = "someNIP" } }, 1, 1);
var resut = _mapper.Map<PaggedResults<CustomerDto>>(source);
var resut2 = _mapper.Map<IPaggedResults<CustomerDto>>(source);
```